# nginx upload module + rails + pupload (jquery multiple upload plugin) multiple uplosding hangs in between

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, files

I have configured nginx with nginx upload module + passenger for rails 2.3.5 on Ubuntu OS.
I am using pulpload (jquery multiple upload plugin) but it hangs after 2 or 3 files get uploaded, But when i remove nginx upload module from nginx.conf and restart the nginx it works fine.

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
 server {
listen 8081;
 # server_name video.local;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
  root /home/livia/Work/test/pulpload_rails2/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
  passenger_enabled on;
  client_max_body_size 1000m;

  rails_env development;          
  location /folders/do_multiple_upload {
             # pass request body to here
             upload_pass @fast_upload_endpoint;
             upload_store /home/livia/Work/test/pulpload_rails2/temp_files/;
                 upload_set_form_field asset[][original_name] "$upload_file_name";
             upload_set_form_field asset[][content_type] "$upload_content_type";
             upload_set_form_field asset[][filepath] "$upload_tmp_path";

      # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
    upload_aggregate_form_field asset[][md5] "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
    upload_aggregate_form_field asset[][size] "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";     

             upload_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
             upload_pass_form_field "^submit$|^authenticity_token$|^format$|^description|^name|^id";
             upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
         }
        location @fast_upload_endpoint {
            passenger_enabled on;  # or this could be your mongrel/thin backend
        }   
  }
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated, because i am struggling with this from a month now.

Comment: Have you used Firebug and/or a HTTP traffic monitor to see what's actually happening with your requests? This could be an issue with NGINX or with the Javascript. Have you checked your NGINX error and access logs?

Comment: Yes, i do checked with firebug and it shows that request is hanged? and no nginx error in error.log